# CORS related issue in production release Outlook Web Addin

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors, outlook-addin, office-js

I have a **Outlook Web Addin**. When tested in **local(Debug environment)** it works properly but when **Web API is released to production** and **Outlook Addin is not yet released to production** (Outlook store), I am getting **CORS** related issue and the **error code** which is returned while making the request is **404** and the error message returned is **Response to preflight does not have HTTP ok status**.

I had similar issue in the **Web API local (Not released to production)**, but I was able to fix it by adding the below piece of code

In Web Config file (Server side)

```
<location path="api/v1/plugin">
  <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Token, Key" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3600" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" /> 
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

In Web API controller changes for HTTP Options

```
[HttpOptions]
    [Route("login")]

    public void EnableCors()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
```

In the client side (Outlook plugin), I am using Ajax to make a call to Web API.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: call,
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    'Token': token, 'Key': keyVal
                },
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                     xhr.withCredentials = true;
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                   createRoamingSetting('apiData',JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                      triggerAlert("error", err.message);
                }
   });
```

When both the above code was included it was working fine in the Debug build. I was able to make request to the Web API(Not released - localhost). But when Web API released to Production, request to Web API returns 404 Error.

And below is the screen shot of the error which I get in the production build.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you called the `HttpConfiguration.EnableCors` method somewhere along the path in your service initialization?  You code route says `login` but your web config section says `plugin`.

Comment: Is the error you see addin specific? Have you tried to make the same web API call from browser?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns : no, I've not called HttpConfiguration.EnableCors . But shouldn't these changes work in SIT since its working on localhost ? 

The config changes seems to be correct because we have multiple route values apart from login ex: api/v1/plugin/login or api/v1/plugin/refresh. so <location path="api/v1/plugin"> should work for both api/v1/plugin/login & api/v1/plugin/refresh. Even if i specify the path as api/v1/plugin/login in config file, i get the same error. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT : API seems to work fine. Since this a POST i cant get a valid data in browser but this works fine in rest clients.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` in web.config within system.webServer > handlers. If this is there then check for HTTP Verbs in request filetering in your IIS, you need to remove the OPTIONS. This worked for me.

[image]